# Convert Button Click to Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP button click method that I want to change from a user clicking the button

```
<asp:Button id="createInvoice" runat="server" OnClick="InvoiceBtn_Click" Text="Create Invoice button" />
```

to executing on `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AsyncMode = true;
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey("accessToken"))
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
        {
            var response = new AuthorizeResponse(Request.QueryString.ToString());
            if (response.State != null)
            {
                if (oauthClient.CSRFToken == response.State)
                {
                    if (response.RealmId != null)
                    {
                        realmId = response.RealmId;
                        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey("realmId"))
                        {
                            dictionary.Add("realmId", realmId);
                        }
                    }

                    if (response.Code != null)
                    {

                        authCode = response.Code;
                        Session["authcodes"] = authCode;
                        output("Authorization code obtained.");
                        PageAsyncTask t = new PageAsyncTask(performCodeExchange);
                        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(t);
                        Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    output("Invalid State");
                    dictionary.Clear();                            
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        oauth.Visible = true;
        connected.Visible = true;
    }
}

#region button click events

public async void InvoiceBtn_Click()
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey("realmId") && dictionary.ContainsKey("accessToken"))
    {
        Action<ServiceContext> apiCallFucntion = new Action<ServiceContext>(CreateInvoiceCall);
        await QBOApiCall(apiCallFucntion);                               
    }
    else
    {
        lblQBOCall.Visible = true;
        lblQBOCall.Text = "Access token not found.";
    }

}
```

Comment: <asp:Button id="createInvoice" runat="server" OnClick="InvoiceBtn_Click" Text="Create Invoice button" />

Answer (score 0):

I changed the final else statement and final line in the method and it works. I'm sure it needs refactoring but it works.

```
    else
        {
            oauth.Visible = true;
            connected.Visible = true;
            InvoiceBtn_Click(createInvoice, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        InvoiceBtn_Click(createInvoice, EventArgs.Empty);
```